# R shiny making sub panels

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a simple solution to making tab panels within the main tab panels created in R shiny?

Here is how I create the main panels:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabSelected",
    tabPanel("Tab1", uiOutput("Tab1")),
    tabPanel("Tab2", uiOutput("Tab2"))
```

I wanted to make new tabs within "Tab1" for various plots I would like to show. I attempted to nest the tabsetPanel function but that doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe because yforget to include them into a new sub-tabsetPanel ?

This works for me :

```
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(

    tabsetPanel(id = "tabSelected",
      tabPanel("Tab1", uiOutput("Tab1")),
      tabPanel("Tab2", uiOutput("Tab2"))
    )

  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {

    output$Tab1 <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(id = "subTabPanel1", 
        tabPanel("subTab11"),
        tabPanel("subTab12")
      )
    })

    output$Tab2 <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(id = "subTabPanel2", 
                  tabPanel("subTab21"),
                  tabPanel("subTab22")
      )
    })
  }
))
```