# Shiny: Independently navigate two tabsetPanels

Tags: r, shiny, tabs

**Is it possible to navigate two menus independently in Shiny?**

I would like to have two tabsetPanels (see the figure below), but if I change between tabs in the upper menu, I want the selected panel in the lower menu to persist.

One way to navigate multiple tabsetPanels is by simply running another Shiny app inside my main app. However, this is not the desired result, because switching tabs in the upper menu will now also affect which tab is open in the lower menu.

Example of what I'm using now:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Normal", shinyAppDir("Distributions/Normal"))),
    tabPanel("Binomial", shinyAppDir("Distributions/Binomial"))
    # etc.
  )
)
```

Where each called app has its own tabsetPanel:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel("Theoretical distribution", plotOutput("plot1")),
              tabPanel("Draw Samples", plotOutput("plot2")),
              tabPanel("Explanation", verbatimTextOutput("explanation"))
  )
)
```

The result:

[image: two_menus]

Comment: Is that what you desire?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206290/r-shiny-making-sub-panels, or you can try `navbarMenu`

Comment: Thanks, that already seems like a better solution then what I'm using now. However, the selected tab in the lower menu is still not persistent when switching between upper tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `id`, `updateTabsetPanel` and `reactiveValues` to achieve what you need.

Use `reactiveValue` to save what is your sub `tabPanel` number is chosen, then use `updateTabsetPanel` to change the default selected sub `tabPanel` when you switch the main `tabPanel`.

Try the following code:

You can use `id`, `updateTabsetPanel` and `reactiveValues` to achieve what you need.

Use `reactiveValue` to save what is your sub `tabPanel` number is chosen, then use `updateTabsetPanel` to change the default selected sub `tabPanel` when you switch the main `tabPanel`.

Try the following code:

```
shiny::runApp(list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(

      tabsetPanel(id = "mainTab",
                  tabPanel("Tab1", tabsetPanel(id = "subTab1", 
                                               tabPanel("subTab11",value=1),
                                               tabPanel("subTab12",value=2),
                                               tabPanel("subTab13",value=3),
                                               selected = 1
                  )),
                  tabPanel("Tab2", tabsetPanel(id = "subTab2", 
                                               tabPanel("subTab21",value=1),
                                               tabPanel("subTab22",value=2),
                                               tabPanel("subTab23",value=3),
                                               selected = 1
                  ))
      )

    ),
    server = function(input, output,session) {

      current_subtab<-reactiveValues(selected=1)


      # when either sub tabPanel change, save the current selected sub tabPanel to reactiveValues
      observeEvent(c(input$subTab1,input$subTab2),{
        if(input$mainTab=="Tab1"){
          current_subtab$selected<-input$subTab1
        }else if(input$mainTab=="Tab2"){
          current_subtab$selected<-input$subTab2
        }
      })

      # when main tabPanel changed, update the default select subPanel value
      observeEvent(input$mainTab,{
        if(input$mainTab=="Tab1"){
          updateTabsetPanel(session,"subTab1",selected = current_subtab$selected)
        }else if(input$mainTab=="Tab2"){
          updateTabsetPanel(session,"subTab2",selected = current_subtab$selected)
        }
      })
    }
  ))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Jim Chen  - is there a way you can help me with a similar one ? Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75188734/how-can-i-get-two-navigation-bar-with-shiny-apps

Comment: @Fran https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75188734/how-can-i-get-two-navigation-bar-with-shiny-apps

Comment: @GaB I take a look of your question, it is just nearly the same as this post.
Just make two `tabsetPanel`  and use `reactiveValues` + `updateTabsetPanel` + `observeEvent` to switch which contents to show