# Limit the number of Shiny slider animations to one at a time

Tags: r, animation, shiny, slider

(This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52547320/8770170).)

I am building a Shiny app with multiple sliders for parameters of a distribution that are plotted. However, I could not find an option for limiting the number of 'active' animations to *one* slider.

**Is it possible to automatically stop one slider's animation when another one is activated?**

Having multiple slider animations on at the same time does not only look bad in my opinion, but it also slows down the app.

MWE:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  ### SLIDER 1 ###
  shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput(
    "mu","Mean", choices = (-99:99)/10, selected = 0, grid = TRUE, 
    animate = animationOptions(interval = 100, loop = TRUE)),

  ### SLIDER 2 ###
  shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput(
    "sigma","Variance", selected = 1, grid = TRUE, 
    choices = apply(expand.grid(1:10, 10^(-2:2)), 1, prod),
    animate = animationOptions(interval = 100, loop = TRUE)),

  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ### PLOT ###
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    x <- seq(-10, 10, 0.01)
    plot(dnorm(x, input$mu, input$sigma) ~ x, type = 'l', yaxs = 'i',
         xlim = c(-9, 9), ylim = c(0, 1/input$sigma/2),
         ylab = 'Probability density')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```